Length filter for list not working correctly
I am making a binary randomizing program that takes text in randomizes it and then output the randomized binary. But in the part that returns 7 digit binary objects to a list isn't working properly.
import random
message = input('What is your message? ')
def encrypter(message):
    shuffled = []
    second = []
    ascii,binary = [],[]
    for letter in message:
        ascii.append(ord(letter))
    for letter in ascii:
        binary.append(int(bin(letter)[2:]))
    print(binary)
    for character in binary:
        for digit in str(character):
            shuffled.append(digit)
    print(shuffled)
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    print(shuffled)
    previous_number = 0
    current_string = ''
    for digit in shuffled:
        if len(current_string) < 7:
            current_string += digit
            previous_number = previous_number + 1 
        elif len(current_string) == 7:
            second.append(int(current_string))
            previous_number = 0
            current_string = ''

I tried changing the elif statement into an else statement but still no luck.
It seems to not be able to read the length of the strings. I also tried to change it from checking the length of the string to using a counter like
number = previous_number+1
if number < 7:
    etc


You're not calling the function

Please provide some debugging details. What's your input? Whatt's the result? What should the result be instead? Also, [mre].

i'm not sure i understand what you're trying to achieve but if you just want the first seven digits of shuffled you can just do ''.join(shuffled[:7]). no loop needed

Nor does the function return anything. Please include enough code so that we can run your program.

and your loop probably would work better if you break instead of repeating the loop and erasing the string again and again (current_string = '')

I have run the code and can get an output by calling the function but it isn't clear at all to me what the problem is and the expected output

Sorry my notifications aren't working properly. I want to input text. Convert it into 7 digit binary bytes. Then turn the binary into a string with the indivdual digits not connected to each other. Shuffle that. And then add all the digits back together, no matter the result. I want random characters. But when I run the code and add input the list I get back has integers of varying size not just 7 digits

So you want to chunk the binary values into 7 digit strings?

Yeah. Basically

What code are you running? Please edit your question to include enough code so that we don't have to guess what you are doing.

That is the full program

But nothing happens when run, apart from the input().

I don't think you are calling the function

... definitely not calling the function, not as the code is presented here. You will get What is your message?  with an opportunity to type in some text, but after an Enter on that, it will not be processed in any way.

To the best of my understanding, you want a chunked output of 7 digit numbers from the randomised binary representation of the input. This will do that. The length check was not failing, but you are resetting the output every time with current_string = '' so, even if you fixed it to return an output, you just keep throwing away the previous string.
Basically, I have just taken the chunking code from the canonical, and then I have added a list comprehension to join the digits back up from the chunked list.
import random

message = input('What is your message? ')

def encrypter(message, chunk_size=7):
    shuffled = []
    second = []
    ascii,binary = [],[]
    for letter in message:
        ascii.append(ord(letter))
    for letter in ascii:
        binary.append(int(bin(letter)[2:]))
    print(binary)
    for character in binary:
        for digit in str(character):
            shuffled.append(digit)
    print(shuffled)
    random.shuffle(shuffled)
    print(shuffled)
    
    chunked = [
        shuffled[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(shuffled), chunk_size)
    ]
    joined = [''.join(item) for item in chunked]
    
    return joined
    
            
result = encrypter(message=message)
print(result)

If my interpretation is correct (and, well you're using random.shuffle() anyway) it should be noted that this is not "encryption" at all.

Thanks for the help. Yes I am aware of the fact that it is not encryption just kind of testing
